# Position:fixed div is wider than body

Tags: css

I have a site whith position:fixed header. This is my css

```
body{
    margin:0;
    font-family: HelveticaNeueW01-55Roma,sans-serif;
}
.header-holder{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:5;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 102px;
    background-color: #1e2d3b;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

And I have

```
@media property @media only screen and (max-device-width: 870px),
 only screen and (max-width: 870px){}
```

In @media I haven't written css for body or .header-holder, but when `@media` works .header-holder becomes wider in 43px than body. I can't understand why to fix the bug

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]. You can use the snippet feature in the stackoverflow editor to include runnable html and css.

Comment: I can give url of the site https://mystroy24.ru/index.php

Comment: It's because you have a h2 element that is too wide to fit. It forces its parent to be wider than `max-width`. You either have to reduce the font size there, or use some sort of clipping, for example `overflow-x: hidden`.

Comment: Thank You overflow-x:hidden realy fixed it, but I don't understand why

Comment: Scroll down and you will see that elements that are too wide such as the h2 "КОНТАКТЫ" are clipped to fit inside the parent element.